# sys.exit doesn't work as expected after try:

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

I tried the following script.

My original intention is that if the command "command_a" in the following code segment is executed successfully, the program ends. Otherwise, it performs additional processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
try:
  command = "command_a"
  subprocess.check_call(command.split())
  print "Woks fine!, and stopping"
  sys.exit()


except:
  pass

print "Continue additional processing"
call_some_additional_processing()
```

However, I notice that `sys.exit()` does not work as expected. Even if subprocess.check_call succeeds, it calls call_some_additional_processing().

Could you please tell me what the reason is, and what would be the best to resolve this problem?

Comment: Incidentally, a good code checker (pylint, pychecker, etc -- or any IDE that integrates one of the aforementioned) should be flagging the root cause (the bare `except`) as a thing that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yep.  A good code checker will also flag `except Exception` even _that_ is almost always too broad to be actually what you want...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sys.exit` works by raising the `SystemExit` exception.  Since you have a bare except, your `SystemExit` exception is getting caught and suppressed.

This is one reason why you should never have bare except clauses.  At the very minimum, catch `Exception`:

```
try:
    sys.exit()
except Exception:
    pass
```

Since [`SystemExit` doesn't inherit from `Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)<sup>1</sup>, it won't get caught.  **As a more general rule, you should never catch an exception if you don't know how to handle it**.  Even catching `Exception` is nearly always more broad than you actually want.

---

Finally, if you ever find yourself in a situation where you're forced to deal with someone else's code and *they* have a bare except that you can't change, you can use `os._exit` to terminate the current process without raising `SystemExit`.  This is generally a bad idea and should only be resorted to in the most dire of circumstances however<sup>2</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` inherit from `BaseException` explicitly so that they *won't* get caught when someone is catching `Exception`.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>Hopefully I've made it clear enough that this last paragraph is meant to give information -- It isn't something that I would ever recommend using ;-)</sup>